# post/pre increment usage in c++ clarrification

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

from past 2 days i have been trying to understand and apply the concept of post/pre increment operators as part of the c++ self learning modules.
    WHat i know:
    post inrement:it first asigns the value then increments.
    pre increment:it first increments then assigns the value.
    so if a=10,e=5
    then ++a*e++ will be 11*5=55
    but when a=2:
    ++a*a++ should be 3*3=9 but when i checked on the c programming terminal it says 12.
    i am not able to grasp how this is possible?'''

Comment: Simply put: Avoid accessing an in/decremented value within the same statement. For performance reasons, the makers of C++ have defined that the order of actual execution is compiler-dependant and may also differ depending where in the code this is.

Comment: oh ok i tried this out on visual studio and the online c compiler and the answer differed.Thanks a ton!!